# Conformal transformation on Riemannian manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry

For a conformal transformation on an $n$-dimensional ($n>2$) Riemannian manifold with boundary. If the transformation becomes an identity on a portion of the boundary, can one conclude that the transformation is actually an identity map?

Comment: Is your manifold connected? What is "portion"? What do you know about conformal maps of Riemannian manifolds? Do you know Ferrand's theorem?

Comment: The key theorem to know about conformal transformations of Riemannian manifolds of dimension $\ge 3$ is in J. Ferrand, The action of conformal transformations on a Riemannian manifold. Math. Ann. 304 (1996), no. 2, 277–291 where she (finally!) proves the Lichnerowicz Conjecture.

Comment: Consider the simplest case: the manifold is just a bounded and connected open set in the Euclidean space with smooth boundary and there is a smooth Riemannian metric on it's closure. Let us say that there is a conformal transformation which is the identity map on the entire boundary. Can one concludes that the conformal transformation is actually an identity map on the entire set? If the transformation is an isometry, the conclusion is true (as an easy consequence of an old result of Myers and Steenrod.

Comment: Dear Simon: Did you read the reference to Ferrand's theorem that I gave? It reduces the problem to the case of isometries.

Comment: I have not read the reference. It's surprise to see that it can be reduced to isometries...Could you give me some details? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Lichnerowicz's conjecture (Ferrand's theorem) states that, with two exceptions (manifolds conformal to the round sphere and the Euclidean space), if $(M,h)$ is a connected Riemannian manifold and $G=Conf(M,h)$ is the group of conformal automorphisms, then there exists a smooth positive function $\rho$  on $M$ such that $G< Isom(M, \rho h)$, where $Isom$ denotes the group of isometries. I did not check, but it very likely that the same proof works for manifolds with boundary.

There will be few more exceptions but they all will be conformally flat and, hence, the uniqueness you are asking for will also hold in the exceptional case since we will be dealing with subgroups of the group of Moebius transformations.

*Ferrand, Jacqueline*, [**The action of conformal transformations on a Riemannian manifold**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01446294), Math. Ann. 304, No. 2, 277-291 (1996). [ZBL0866.53027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0866.53027).

From your comment, it is clear that you know how to finish the proof in the case of isometric maps (it is indeed quite easy).

Remark. 1. Ferrand's theorem has complicated history that Ferrand discusses in the introduction to her paper. Briefly: Ferrand gave a sketch of a proof for compact manifolds in 1971; in 1972 Alexeevsky gave a proof in the general case. It turned out later on that his proof was incorrect. Ferrand extended her argument from the compact case to general manifolds in 1996.

2. For the uniqueness theorem to hold, you need the manifold to be connected and a "piece" of the boundary to mean an open nonempty subset of the boundary.

**Edit.** I checked the argument in the case you mentioned in a comment, namely, when $(M,h)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold with smooth boundary. Suppose that $f\in Conf(M,h)$ and $f$ fixes 3 distinct points on the boundary of $M$. Then the subgroup of $Conf(M,h)$ generated by $f$ is relatively compact in $Conf(M,h)$ due to the **convergence property** of $Conf(M,h)$ and the latter holds regardless of whether $M$ has boundary or not (see the relevant discussion in Ferrand's paper, section 7). Once you have relative compactness, you will find an $f$-invariant conformal metric on $(M,h)$ (of the form $\rho h$) by averaging.

Comment: Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.